# strange errors when using parsertree

Tags: rascal

I am playing around with the parsing of code using the java15 syntax.

I noticed that when parsing an entire class it gives me an error if the class file ends with an empty line. I wrote some code to remove these empty lines before parsing but is there a more structural solution? Or am I missing something?

Related: when I am trying to parse a single method: as soon as I change something to the location of the accolades `{ }`  ( on a separate line or not for example) I receive an error.

`|std:///ParseTree.rsc|(14967,5,<455,80>,<455,85>): ParseError(|java+class:///smallsql/database/language/Language_it|(10537,0,<152,0>,<152,0>))
        at parse(|std:///ParseTree.rsc|(14967,5,<455,80>,<455,85>))
        at $root$(|prompt:///|(0,7,<1,0>,<1,7>))
        at *** somewhere ***(|std:///ParseTree.rsc|(14967,5,<455,80>,<455,85>))
        at parse(|std:///ParseTree.rsc|(14967,5,<455,80>,<455,85>))
        at $root$(|prompt:///|(0,7,<1,0>,<1,7>))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you are parsing using code like so:

- `parse(#CompilationUnit, file)`
- `[CompilationUnit] file`

But: a `CompilationUnit` does not start or end with `layout` notation.

To solve this, you should declare the start non-terminal of a grammar like so:

```
start syntax CompilationUnit = ... ;
layout L = [\t\n\r\ ]*; // it's necessary to have L be nullable
```

and this will (internally and hidden) generate for you a new production, like so:

```
syntax start[CompilationUnit] = L CompilationUnit top L;
```

With this, you can then parse a whole file which might end with layout:

- `parse(#start[CompilationUnit], file)`
- `[start[CompilationUnit]] file`

To extract the CompilationUnit the `top` field comes in handy:

- `CompilationUnit u = parse(#CompilationUnit, file).top`

Comment: Still a lot to learn :) So the problem is in fact the data I am parsing contains excessive elements?

Comment: It's just that you are parsing something which has a different syntax, a language with spaces at the end versus a language without.